# PHP/MySQL: Combine UPDATE queries?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance, sql-update

Stack Overflow. PHP and SQL novice here.

As part of a multi-user private messaging system I've been trying to write to learn how to properly interact with a database through PDO, I have two separate queries that are executed when a user deletes a message, via a single function *deleteMessage()*:

```
UPDATE messages SET s_deleted = 1 WHERE id = :id AND sender = :sender
UPDATE messages SET r_deleted = 1 WHERE id = :id AND recipient = :recipient
```

They work well enough to accomplish what I need but running both one after the other, as I am currently doing, doesn't strike me as particularly efficient.

I looked into [CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html), but as far as I could understand it wasn't quite what I needed.

Is there a way to combine these two queries so that I'm not peppering my database with extraneous requests? Would I be better off splicing each query into a separate function, i.e., *deleteMessageSender()* and *deleteMessageRecipient()*?

Comment: What's even the purpose for filtering by `sender` or `recipient`, assuming `id` is the primary key of table `messages`?

Comment: I apologize, I probably should have specified. Sender and recipient are foreign key columns that correspond to the id column of my users table.The reason I'm attempting this double-sort thing is so that users can keep deleted messages in their outbox, even if the person they were sent to has deleted them.

Comment: You miss my point - if `id` is the primary key of messages, `where id = :id` can already only return a single row. Why filter it on the extra fields as well then, or are you using it to doublecheck you're actually deleting the right message? If so - that's not a good way.

Comment: Oh, I see. Yes, that was the reason. I know it's not really related to my initial question, but while I'm here, do you have any advice on improving that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE messages
SET s_deleted = IF(sender = :sender, 1, s_deleted),
    r_deleted = IF(recipient = :recipient, 1, r_deleted)
WHERE id = :id
```

As you can see, the "trick" is to simply set a column to its existing value when the criteria isn't met, so it only gets updated when necessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE messages 
SET s_deleted = IF(sender = :sender, 1, s_deleted),
r_deleted = IF (recipient = :recipient, 1, r_deleted)
WHERE id = :id AND 
(sender = :sender OR recipient = :recipient);
```

Comment: I don't think PDO allows you to use the same placeholder multiple times, you need to give them different names.

Comment: I don't use PDO much (and now I've got at least one good reason not to). https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=33886 "It's not portable" - WTF?

Comment: @Barmar is right about that. That accounted for, your query also worked, but his was a bit more readable. Thank you for the effort!

Comment: Well, if you use mysqli it doesn't have named placeholders at all, just `?`. So this is no worse.

Comment: ...except that I set the deleted to the value of the user - whoops - fixing for posterity...